# Using IF statements in Underscore.js/Backbone.js templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am receiving a JSON object where one of the value is `null`. The JSON looks like:

```
[{"id":"1096","price":null,
```

Right now, it is outputting a `NULL` string to the webpage with the following code. *(I am using the template engine in Backbone.js/Underscore.js)*

```
<div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
```

Because I want to hide the entire `div` if no `price` is returned, I added the `if` statements:

```
<% if (price) { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>
```

However it seems to still output the `div.subtitle`. What am I doing wrong? I also tried the following but they did not work

```
<% if (typeof(price) != "undefined") { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>

<% if (price != null) { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>

<% if (price != "null") { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>
```

**I suspect this has to do with using `if` statements inside Underscore.js's templates**

Comment: are you sure you're passing in a single object from your array? can we see the entirety of your underscore template and what value you're passing in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh, don't you want (no exclamation mark)

```
<% if (price) { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>
```

Because you are current saying if there is no price then display the price...which makes no sense.

Comment: Yes u are right! I changed to `if(price)`, but it still does not work. I suspect it has to do with using `if` statements in the underscore.js's templates

Answer (score 2):

`null` is not `undefined`!

If your json-object is correctly decoded, then checking `(price)` or `(price != null)` should be fine.

Comment: `console.log(price)` gives me an `object`. But `if(!price)` does not work! :-/ I am using backbone.js's `this.myCollectionName.fetch()` to get the JSON object and decode it.

Comment: well, then this is obvious. Objects are always true. `console.log(price)`  should give you `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be a `==` (in this case `!==`) for comparison

```
<% if (price !== null) { %>
    <div class="subtitle">$<%= price %></div>
<% } %>
```

e.g look at the warning of this [Jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/exojox/edit#javascript,html) line